# Android Studio Compose Material3 template theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When you create a new project in Android Studio selecting the template Jetpack Compose Material3 you get a project which defines following in themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.ComposeMaterial3" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

1. Is this being used by the project at all since the Composables
   reference Material3 styles? (ComposeMaterial3Theme)
2. Why does this not set as parent "Theme.Material3..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app you can define more compose themes (for example in the `Theme.kt` file).
To apply one of them you have to wrap your composables with the favorite theme.

For example:

```
setContent {
    MyCustomM3Theme {
      //...your composables
    }
}
```

About the theme defined in the xml, you can extend a M3 theme for example: `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="Theme.ComposeMaterial3" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

but the composables **don't use** it. They use the compose theme.
The theme defined in the `themes.xml` is used in the material components library (and other small parts as status bars).

> Why does this not set as parent "Theme.Material3..."?

Your theme is defined as:

```
@Composable
fun MyCustomM3Theme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    //...

    MaterialTheme(  //<---
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

The **`MaterialTheme`** is defined in the package `androidx.compose.material3`

Comment: Hm , this doesn't really address my questions.

Comment: @David Sorry my bad, I didn't understand that you was referring to the xml theme. I've updated the answer. May be there is an error in the template file, of course you can use a M3 theme, but please note that composables don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's being used. The app itself can still use xml themes for things like the status bar colour, and the app icon. A good example project is https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat. You can see how they achieve the "material you" styling for multiple android versions using the Material3 theme in that project.
2. That would be a question for the template designer. In my opinion, if you look at the volume of theme based configuration required in JetChat to achieve consistent theming across multiple Android versions, I can believe that the Compose Material3 template is trying to keep things a bit more simple to highlight the concepts of material 3 in Compose. (Absolutely no evidence to back that up though).